# YouTube video play only for 10 seconds in loop

Tags: youtube

I am using YouTube URL for embed in my website but the problem is I want to play video only for 10 seconds in loop.

Is there any parameter for passing with YouTube embed URL, so could anyone please tell me how to do this, like I am doing with this URL but its start after 10 seconds but I want to play only 10 seconds.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGRgHj9hsqw&t=0m10s
```

Comment: yourepeat.com comes to mind, you can construct a similar link with parameters for both the beginning and end times, or alternatively construct a GIF from a portion of the video. I'm beginning to wonder if this is totally on-topic for this site, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! there is a parameter "end", you can set this parameter in your url, 
to know more about youtube parameter you could refer the below link
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters